# Ruby how to return instance evaled array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

I have method in my rails model which returns anonymous class:

```
def today_earnings
Class.new do
  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end

  def all
    @user.store_credits.where(created_at: Time.current.beginning_of_day..Time.current.end_of_day)
  end

  def unused
    all.map { |el| el.amount - el.amount_used }.instance_eval do
      def to_f
        reduce(:+)
      end
    end
  end

  def used
    all.map(&:amount_used).instance_eval do
      def to_f
        reduce(:+)
      end
    end
  end
end.new(self)
```

end

I want to achieve possibility to chain result in that way `user.today_earning.unused.to_f` and I have some problems with instance eval because when I call `to_f` on result it's undefined method, I guess it is due to ruby copying returned value so the instance gets changed, is it true? And if I'm correct how can I change the code to make it work. Also I'm wondering if making new model can be better solution than anomyous class thus I need advice if anonymous class is elegant in that case and if so how can I add to_f method to returned values

Comment: I don't think you need this complexity. A new model would probably be cleaner. Also, you don't calculate or return anything in `instance_eval`, you only define `to_f`, so you then try to call the method `to_f` on the `:to_f` Symbol. You might try to add `self` at the end of the `instance_eval`  block but it feels like a hack.

Comment: I assume that you have a `store_credits` table with `amount` and `amount_used` columns? If so, the obvious solution would be a database query for getting the results.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Anonymous class makes the code much complex. I would suggest a seperate class. It will solve 2 problems here.

1. defining some anonymous class again and again when we call the `today_earnings` method.
2. Readability of the code.

Now coming to actual question, you can try something similar to `hash_with_indifferent_access`. The code looks as follows.

```
class NumericArray < Array
   def to_f
     reduce(:+)
   end
end

Array.class_eval do
   def with_numeric_operations
      NumericArray.new(self)
   end
end
```

Usage will be:

```
Class Earnings
  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end

  def all
    @user.store_credits.where(created_at: Time.current.beginning_of_day..Time.current.end_of_day)
  end

  def unused
    all.map { |el| el.amount - el.amount_used }.with_numeric_operations
  end

  def used
    all.map(&:amount_used).with_numeric_operations
  end
end
```

Comment: Subclassing Array or any of the other classes in the core (String, Numeric etc.) is a bad idea. They are written in C and do not behave like normal ruby classes. Better would be to use SimpleDelegator and wrap the array. https://words.steveklabnik.com/beware-subclassing-ruby-core-classes

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a "clever" but ridiculously over-complicated way to do something that can be simply and efficiently done in the database.

```
User.joins(:store_credits)
    .select(
       'users.*',
       'SUM(store_credits.amount_used) AS amount_used',
       'SUM(store_credits.amount) - amount_used AS unused',
    )
    .where(store_credits: { created_at: Time.current.beginning_of_day..Time.current.end_of_day })
    .group(:id)
```